# linker issues in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

so I am sort of new to using VSCode, decided to do a switch from eclipse to vscode since it look more appealing to the eyes. So I have been following some setup videos and I have been running into this linker issue and cannot seem to get it fix, so here i am asking for some guidance. Thanks in advance. Here is the error output:

```
rgmac@MacBook-Pro trst % cd "/Users/rgmac/Desktop/VScode/c++ws/trst/" && g++ t.cpp -o t && "/Users/rgmac/Desktop/VScode/c++ws/trst/"t
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: does `t.cpp` have a `main` function? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: i was testing to see if i can run multiple files, so t.cpp and t.h are just two fiiles that have a void function that prints out hi.